# XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation works but still throws error when unmarshalling

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have a class which contains a Geometry object from vividsolutions. This class has no default 0 parameter constructor, because it can only instantiated by an factory.

So I annotated the geometry object inside the class with @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(GeometryXmlAdapter.class) telling it I want to handle the marshalling and unmarshalling myself.

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "fm_point")
public class GeoCodePoint {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    /**
     * The point encoded as ST_POINT in PostGIS / H2 GeoDB
     */
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(GeometryXmlAdapter.class)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(Point,4326)", nullable = true)
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
    private Geometry point;
```

This is the XmlAdapter:

```
public class GeometryXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Geometry> {

    @Override
    public Geometry unmarshal(String simpleFeatureString) throws     Exception {

        Geometry geometry = null;

        try {
            GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 4326);
            WKTReader wktReader = new WKTReader(geometryFactory);
            geometry = wktReader.read(simpleFeatureString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return geometry;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Geometry geometry) throws Exception {

        return geometry.toText();
    }
}
```

For both processes, marshalling and unmarshalling, the XmlAdapter works. But in the case of unmarshalling after successfully generated a geometry object from a String with the help of the factory I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ClassFactory.create0(Unknown Source)
```

It is like the code has called my XmlAdapter (debuging proves that it enters the method) by afterwards it ignores my geometry object and tries to unmarshall it all by itself.

Do I miss here something???